# How do I make my spaceship keep momentum in the direction where thrust has been given, regardless of rotation?

Tags: python, game-physics

I am trying to make the spaceship controls function as follows:

Pressing W adds momentum in the direction the spaceship is facing.
Rotating the spaceship when the ship has momentum should not affect the direction of the momentum.
Adding thrust to the spaceship after rotating, whilst having momentum in a different direction, should ADD momentum in the new direction, without removing the previous momenum (unless you are thrusting in the opposite direction, then it should slowly cancel it out and eventually add momentum in the opposite direction).

I managed to get much of it to work, but currently the momentum is added continously in the direction the ship is facing. Basically, turning while you have momentum causes the ship to turn like a car.

```
def blit_rotate_center(win, image, top_left, angle):
    rotated_image = pygame.transform.rotate(image, angle)
    new_rect = rotated_image.get_rect(center = image.get_rect(topleft = top_left).center)
    win.blit(rotated_image, new_rect.topleft)

class PlayerShip:
    def __init__(self):
        self.img = assets.SPACE_SHIP_1
        self.max_vel = 12
        self.vel = 0
        self.acceleration = 0.02
        self.rotation_vel = 0.8
        self.angle = 0
        self.x = 400
        self.y = 400
        self.drag = 0.015
        self.acc_angle = 0
        self.vertical = 0
        self.horizontal = 0
        
    
    def rotate(self, left = False, right = False):
        if left:
            self.angle += self.rotation_vel
        elif right:
            self.angle -= self.rotation_vel
    
    def draw(self, win):
        blit_rotate_center(win, self.img, (self.x, self.y), self.angle)
        # Moving the player according to angle
        radians = math.radians(self.angle)
        self.vertical = math.cos(radians) * self.vel
        self.horizontal = math.sin(radians) * self.vel
        self.y -= self.vertical
        self.x -= self.horizontal
        self.reduce_speed()
    
    def key_input(self):
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keys[pygame.K_a]:
            self.rotate(left = True)
        if keys[pygame.K_d]:
            self.rotate(right = True)
        if keys[pygame.K_w]:
            self.move_forward()
        if keys[pygame.K_s]:
            self.move_backward()
    
    def move_forward(self):
        self.vel = min(self.vel + self.acceleration, self.max_vel)

    def move_backward(self):
        self.vel = min(self.vel - self.acceleration, self.max_vel)
        if self.vel < self.max_vel - self.max_vel * 2:
            self.vel = self.max_vel - self.max_vel * 2
    
    def reduce_speed(self):
        if self.vel < 0:
            self.vel += self.drag
        elif self.vel > 0:
            self.vel -= self.drag
```

I figure it has something to do with the self.angle being updated constantly, but I have run out of ideas on how to get this to work.

I tried storing the velocity in multiple variables, applying them within different functions, etc.

Comment: Velocity and acceleration should be vectors, not scalars. They have inherent direction that you need to keep track of which, in your case, are unlikely to be the same as which way the ship is facing.